# Ansible error change handler is not defined

Tags: handler, ansible

I'm trying to run my first playbook to install Java on four servers and subsequently define a JAVA_HOME environment variable.

```
ansible-playbook site.yml --check
PLAY [crave_servers] **********************************************************

GATHERING FACTS ***************************************************************
ok: [54.174.151.196]
ok: [54.174.197.35]
ok: [54.174.207.83]
ok: [54.174.208.240]

TASK: [java | install Java JDK] ***********************************************
changed: [54.174.197.35]
changed: [54.174.151.196]
changed: [54.174.208.240]
changed: [54.174.207.83]
ERROR: change handler (setvars) is not defined
```

I've placed my site.yml under /etc/ansible

```
---
- hosts: crave_servers
  remote_user: ubuntu
  sudo: yes
  roles:
  - java
```

I've placed main.yml under /etc/ansible/java/tasks

```
---
- name: install Java JDK
  apt: name=default-jdk state=present
  notify:
     - setvars
```

I've placed main.yml under /etc/ansible/handlers

```
---
- name: setvars
  shell:  echo "JAVA_HOME=\"/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64\"" >> /etc/environment
```

Now I'm not sure if the syntax is structure of my handlers is correct. But it's obvious from the output that Ansible is able to find the correct role and execute the correct task. But the task can't find the handler. 
Nobody else seems to have the same problem. And I don't really know how to debug it because my ansible version seems to be missing the config file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put your handler to `/etc/ansible/java/handlers/main.yml`

As handlers are part of a role.

Remarks:

- You should not use your handler as it would paste the line into `/etc/environment` each time you call this playbook. I would recommend the [lineinefile](http://docs.ansible.com/lineinfile_module.html) module.
- You should reconsider your decision to put ansible playbooks into `/etc`

Comment: Thank you for going the extra mile in your answer. You're correct that the handler using shell is not idempotent, I just wanted to investigate Ansible's shell capability in cases where a module doesn't exist.